# Migrate images, containers, files, databases with docker to another server

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I think I've read almost all the articles and posts here on stackoverflow as well, but I can't quite understand the logic and get an optimal result.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network


volumes:
    dbdata:
    src:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli && apachectl restart
EXPOSE 80
```

My goal is to replicate everything including the site and database to another server.

I exported all the images with this command:

```
docker save $(docker images | grep -v \<none\> | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1 ":" $2 }') -o allinone.tar
```

I move this .tar file to the new server, along with the docker-compose.yml, .env, Dockerfile.

Now how do I migrate the site files and the database too?

Is there no way to simplify all these steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your image doesn't contain your application's code, and you inject it through a bind mount, you also need to separately copy your application code.

You're not getting much benefit from using Docker this way.  You can use a system-automation tool like Ansible, Chef, or Salt Stack to copy your application code and deployment files to the target system, but those tools can also install the application runtime and database dependency.

A better approach would be to include your application's code in your image.  You will also need access to a Docker registry.  Docker Hub is convenient, most public cloud providers have one (ECR, GCR, ACR, ...), and there are several third-party hosted options; you can also run your own locally.

To include your code in the image, add to your Dockerfile the line:

```sh
COPY src /var/www/html/
```

In your `docker-compose.yml` file you need to tell Docker to actually use the image you're building.  You need to tell it to `build:` the image; you also need to tell it the name of the image in the repository.  Do not overwrite the code in the image with `volumes:`.  (I would also remove all of the `networks:` blocks; Compose will provide a network named `default` for you.)

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  php:
    build: .
    image: exper1/php-app # or another registry-specific name
    ports:
      - 80:80
  db:
    # as in the question, except without the networks: block or container_name:
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Now you can `docker-compose build && docker-compose push` to push your custom image to Docker Hub (or elsewhere).

If you can't reconstruct the database data, you need to separately copy it.  The Docker documentation describes how to [back up and restore named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes); in this context you'd need to do something like

```
docker-compose run -v $PWD:/export -w /var/lib/mysql db \
  tar cvzf /export/db.tar.gz .
```

Now you need to copy the `docker-compose.yml` file and the exported `db.tar.gz` file to the other system.  You do not need the Dockerfile or the application source code.  Remove the `build:` line from `docker-compose.yml`; re-import the database data

```
docker-compose run -v $PWD:/export -w /var/lib/mysql db \
  tar xvzf /export/db.tar.gz
```

and you can now run

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and it will pull the image, containing all of the application source, from Docker Hub or your other registry server.

(If you are in a cloud environment, there is a good argument to use a hosted database solution, with automatic backups and snapshots.  If you're running this on an Amazon EC2 instance, you could use ECR for your image registry and RDS for your database, for example.  This would require further modifications to the `docker-compose.yml` to not start the database and to point at the external database instead.)

Comment: Thanks finally something clear. I'd like to ask you more questions. I don't want to use any Docker registry for now, so to switch between servers I have to move the docker-compose, Dockerfile, code and db separately, or is there a way to move them together? I restored the src volume otherwise it didn't work. The database backup command does not give any errors in exporting and importing, but my database is not there

Comment: If you want to specifically want to transplant the code separately from the image, I'd suggest using a tool like Ansible to provision PHP directly on the target host, and ignoring Docker.  You do need to separately move the image, the database data, and the `docker-compose.yml` to the target system (you could build a deployment script that did this all through a single tar file).